# Flightgear starts then chrashes

Tags: 12.04, games

I have installed flightgear but when I type `fgfs` in terminal it starts loading but when it is almost done loading it crashes with this error:

```
failure to revalidate BOs - badness
fgfs: ../../radeon/radeon_cs_gem.c:181: cs_gem_write_reloc: Assertion `boi->space_accounted' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Tried the solution but failed again KI266 dme indicator #0 initialized
loading scenario 'nimitz_demo'
creating 3D noise texture... DONE
weather util initialized ...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run  `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 fgfs`